# Count cells with value in column G, if value in column C equals value from cell B4

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Tried different approaches, but the best I could came with is:

```
=IF($C$2:$C$65365=B4, COUNTA($G$2:$G$65365))
```

but it returns `#SPILL`

|  | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 10/26/2022 | The Quarry | Hunter | 1:39 | Chest | The Dragon's Shadow |
|  | 10/26/2022 | The Quarry | Hunter | 1:57 | Chest |  |
|  | 10/30/2022 | Perdition | Titan | 3:30 | Chest | Actium War Rig |
|  | 10/30/2022 | Perdition | Titan | 3:06 | Chest |  |

Comment: try this `=IF(@$C$2:$C$65365=B4, COUNTA($G$2:$G$65365))` adding an [Implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)

Comment: Thank you for reply! It did get rid of `#SPILL`, but still counts all cells with value in column G even if the value in column C ≠ B4

Comment: not here update your post. use **[Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)**

Comment: Done. So I want to count all cells with value in column G, only if value column C equals "The Quarry". In that case it would 1, but it count all cells and returns 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[COUNTIFS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D7</kbd>

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C5,C7,G2:G5,"<>")
```

---

Using **[SUMPRODUCT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E7</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C5=C7)*(G2:G5<>""))
```

---

Using some fancy functions to simplify, clarify and improved performance. **[LET()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F7</kbd>

```
=LET(criteria_range1,C2:C5,criteria1,C7,
criteria_range2,G2:G5,criteria2,"<>",
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,criteria2))
```